# how do i convert 14 bit bayer data to 12 bit data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to convert  14bit bayer (raw ) data to 12-bit raw data in python. I know I need to use bit shifting right. but I am not sure how do I use it in python
i tried this 
newbayer=np.right_shift(bayer,2)

not sure i am doing it right.

Comment: modifying this question as I also did                                                                      def shift_bits(bayer):
    return (bayer >> 2) getting error in both scenarios                                 
  TypeError: ufunc 'right_shift' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: Can you show us an example of input, and the expected output? Where are you getting your "raw data" from?

Comment: I have camera raw data it is 14bit data